# Normal extension of rational numbers with given Galois group

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

At the end of Emil Artin's *Modern Higher Algebra: Galois Theory* -- the original Courant Institute notes by Albert A. Blank, Summer 1947 -- he asks whether given a group, it is always possible to determine a normal extension of the field of rational numbers which has that group."The answer is probably yes," he says, "but nobody has succeeded in finding a proof." Has the question been answered?

Comment: The problem should be still open, but for a large collection of groups, the claim is known to be true. In particular, for every solvable, for every alternating and for every symmetric group, the claim is known to be true.

Comment: It's called the "inverse galois problem" and it's still open and considered extremely difficult.  David Harbater worked on it a lot and he seemed to think they'd conquer it soon but I'm not sure that happened yet, I'll ask him.

Comment: @GregoryGrant  Ah, thank you for the name of the problem, which opens up much online information.

Comment: @Commic No problem, I figured the name would get you to the info you needed.

Comment: We studied the "inverse Galois problem" for a special topic in Galois theory and it was tricky. As the name suggests, instead of working out Galois groups *directly* you start with a finite group that you *want* to be a Galois group and see if you can find the Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ that lets this happen. Interesting that someone may have cracked it.